# two xAxes horizontal bar chart Charts.js

Tags: chart.js

I'm struggling to get the correct xAxis setup with charts.js and a two-axes horizontal bar chart. JsFiddle link is below. The trouble is that I'm trying to show two different scales in the same chart. One is a high number (price) and the other is a low number (quantity).

https://jsfiddle.net/clevelandbuckeye/Luaf2tm4/533/

I'm using the second x-Axis in the options property but the label is showing up as the Month, not the quantity! How can the quantity be displayed?

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "# Deals",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    borderWidth: 2,
    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
    hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    data: [15, 19, 5, 16, 1, 12, 8],
      xAxisID:'x1',
  }, {
    label: "$Money",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(55,99,132,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    borderWidth: 1,
    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(55,99,132,0.4)",
    hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    data: [265, 459, 320, 181, 456, 555, 1040]
  }]
};
var option = {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          color: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
          id: 'x1',
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          }},
          {
            id: 'x2',
            gridLines: {
              display: false
            }
          }]
      }
    };
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

    var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'horizontalBar',
      data: data,
      options: option
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ꜰɪʀꜱᴛ**

set **`xAxisID: 'x2'`** for the second dataset, as such :

```
datasets: [{
      ...
   }, {
      label: "$Money",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(55,99,132,0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(55,99,132,0.4)",
      hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
      data: [265, 459, 320, 181, 456, 555, 1040],
      xAxisID: 'x2',
   }]
```

**ꜱᴇᴄᴏɴᴅ**

set **`type: 'linear'`** and **`position: 'bottom'`** for the second x-axis, like so :

```
xAxes: [{
         ...
      }, {
         id: 'x2',
         type: 'linear',
         position: 'bottom',
         gridLines: {
            display: false
         }
      }]
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
   labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
   datasets: [{
      label: "# Deals",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
      borderWidth: 2,
      hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
      hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
      data: [15, 19, 5, 16, 1, 12, 8],
      xAxisID: 'x1',
   }, {
      label: "$Money",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(55,99,132,0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(55,99,132,0.4)",
      hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
      data: [265, 459, 320, 181, 456, 555, 1040],
      xAxisID: 'x2',
   }]
};
var option = {
   scales: {
      yAxes: [{
         gridLines: {
            display: true,
            color: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"
         }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
         id: 'x1',
         gridLines: {
            display: false
         }
      }, {
         id: 'x2',
         type: 'linear',
         position: 'bottom',
         gridLines: {
            display: false
         }
      }]
   }
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'horizontalBar',
   data: data,
   options: option
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```